# Touchable opacity button guidance

Tags: react-native

I am new to react coding only just this week for a project I am doing. I have created a login page using touchable opacities for the actual login button, but I cannot figure out how to make that button navigate to the home screen once the user details have been added.

I have tried/followed various examples but not having any luck. If anyone could give some guidance on what the line of code should be for this section it would be a massive help. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but it is doing my head in!

Probably such a basic thing but first time using React-native.

Here seems to be the area I am having issues with. I took away what I tried because it was probably completely wrong.

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Login</Text>

 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Could someone confirm what should be imported if anything else? I tried to import various types of navigations and also advise on what the correct code would be to put in this section before I throw my laptop out the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")}>
      <Text>Login</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

In your App.js add the following code

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

import Credits from "./src/Screens/Login"; //Import from where your Login.js is
import Home from "./src/Screens/Home";     //Import from where your Home.js is

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home, navigationOptions: { header: null } }, 
  LoginScreen: { screen: Login, navigationOptions: { header: null} }
});
const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default App;
```

Comment: Ah perfect thank you, will give that a go when home. I was defiantly no where near right then haha.